# How to resolve ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector on designtime?

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

Why I can't resolve ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector on designtime?
(On run time it works)
Designer (VS2010) shows an exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation.

and

> System.NullReferenceException Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Temp1">
       <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" Height="20" Width="Auto"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:TemplateSelector x:Key="mySelector"/>
    <Grid>
       <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource mySelector}">
          <ContentControl.Content>
               1
          </ContentControl.Content>
       </ContentControl>      
    </Grid>
 </Window.Resources>
```

C#:

```
    public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
             //int num = int.Parse(item.ToString());
             Window win = Application.Current.MainWindow;
             return win.FindResource("Temp1") as DataTemplate;//load template based on num...
         }

    }
```

Comment: Is your class really called `myTemplateSelector`? That does not match the XAML.

Comment: the calling is ok, it's a misspell. (if it works on runtime it means it's ok)

Comment: You should still edit your question though...

Comment: I had this problem and it was caused by the fact that in design time it may not have some objects as it does in run-time. Make sure you rebuild your solution after trying some of the examples here, because I had to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H.B. is right about `Application.Current.MainWindow` being `null` at design time. Here's a better way to retrieve the resource by name:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate( object item, DependencyObject container ) {
    var element = container as FrameworkElement;
    if ( element != null ) {
        var template = element.TryFindResource( "Temp1" ) as DataTemplate;
        if ( template != null ) {
            return template;
        }
    }
    return base.SelectTemplate( item, container );
}
```

Other parts of your code are still incomplete, though, so I hope you're just in the middle of it. Your `DataTemplate` should have bindings, for example, rather than hard-coded values.

Comment: well it's a example, ContentControl will be inside datagrid columnheader style, it will load specific template for each column header (based on header's name)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `Application.Current.MainWindow` is not set at design time.